# How to import and use CreateML or CreateMLUI in Xcode

Tags: swift, coreml

I would like to use the new `CreateML` and `CreateMLUI` Swift frameworks.

But when I write:

```
import CreateML
```

Xcode gives me an error:

> No such module 'CreateML'

How can I use those in Xcode?

Comment: CreateML is only available in PlayGrounds and the CreateML app unfortunately as of this writing.

Answer (score 11):

To import CoreML or CoreMLUI you need to get latest software:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/
2. Install macOS Mojave 10.14 beta version.
3. Install Xcode 10 beta.
4. Create a **macOS platform** template.

HOW TO CREATE YOUR OWN MLMODEL: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/create_ml/creating_an_image_classifier_model

Use free MLModels provided by apple: https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/run-a-model/

Answer (score 9):

You need to

1. Have Mojave installed
2. Install Xcode 10 beta
3. Create a macOS template playground (not iOS)

Answer (score 1):

Install Mojave* and Xcode 10. 
Create a new playground and make sure you select macOS as the target (e.g. macOS Single View).
Type in `import CreateMLUI`- it should compile without problems.

(*)macOS Mojave is officially available since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 10 - beta 6
You don't have to upgrade to Mojave. The newest Xcode - beta already supports 10.13.x. (From Apple Developer Forums).

I followed this step to try CreateML framework.

1. Upgraded to latest MacOS (Not Mojave)
2. Upgraded latest Xcode - beta.
3. Create playground in macOS template (Default is iOS template)

Then, I can use createMLUI.